# Getting __init__ variable

Tags: python, class, variables, object, function

```
class first(object):
    def __init__(self, room, speed):
        self.position = room
        self.speed = 20
        direction = random.randint(0,359)
class second(first):
    def __init__(self)
        self.way = first.direction
        self.now = first.self.position
```

I am getting an error, how to get variable from `__init__` of another class?

Answer (score 8):

You cannot. `direction` is a *local* variable of the `__init__` function, and an such not available outside of that function.

The variable is not used *at all* even; it could be removed from the function and nothing would change.

The `__init__` method is intended to set attributes on the newly created instance, but your `second` class seems to want to find the attributes on the `first` *class* instead. You cannot do that either, as those attributes you want to access are only set in `__init__`. You can only find `position` on *instances* of `first`, not on the `first` class itself.

Perhaps you wanted to initialize the parent class first, and actually store `position` on `self`:

```
class first(object):
    def __init__(self, room, speed):
        self.position = room
        self.speed = 20
        self.direction = random.randint(0,359)

class second(first):
    def __init__(self, room, speed)
        super(second, self).__init__(room, speed)
        self.way = self.direction
        self.now = self.position
```

Now `self` has the `direction` and `position` attributes defined and your `second.__init__` function can access those there.

Comment: +1 for the edit guessing what the OP really wants.  I was putting together the same code but you beat me :)